# Classic ASP website not sending email for one user

Tags: iis, asp-classic

My website is not sending notification emails only when a particular user posts the form that would send an email. All other users can post the same form and the website will send the email correctly.

When I get the user to perform the action, I can see in the IIS log the following entry:

```
2016-04-22 00:17:30 [Server IP address] POST /url/do_update_movement.asp |511|8004020e|- 80 [Username] [Client IP address] Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+InfoPath.3) 500 0 0 608
```

Note the error code 500 on the end. All other users posting the same form have success code 200.

Answer (score 1):

The `|511|8004020e|` in the IIS log entry turned out to be the clue. No other entries in the log (successful form submits with HTTP code 200 being logged) had this piece of information in the log entry.

For example:

```
2016-04-22 00:45:31 [Server IP address] POST /url/do_update_movement.asp - 80 [Username] [Client IP address] Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+InfoPath.3) 200 0 0 109
```

The `8004020e` turns out to be some kind of error code.
I was not able to find a good definition for this error code, but it's something to do with the sender not being valid.

I checked the user's listed email address and it was incorrect, being in the form `username@domain.com@domain.com`. Probably a copy/paste error. Fixing the user's email solved the issue.

I posted this in the hopes that it will help the next person who tries to google error code `8004020e` and now there will be at least one relevant result!